# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{2+(-1)^n}{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have to show that the following series convergences:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{2+(-1)^n}{n+1}$$

I have tried the following:

- The alternating series test cannot be applied, since $\frac{2+(-1)^n}{n+1}$ is not monotonically decreasing.
- I tried splitting up the series in to series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{2}{n+1}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$. I proofed the convergence of the first series using the alternating series test, but then i realized that the second series is divergent.
- I also tried using the ratio test: for even $n$ the sequence converges to $\frac{1}{3}$, but for odd $n$ the sequence converges to $3$. Therefore the ratio is also not successful.

I ran out of ideas to show the convergence of the series.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: May be you could separate the odd terms and the even terms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not convergent. To see this, let
$$
a_n = (-1)^n\frac{2}{n+1},\qquad b_n =\frac{1}{n+1},\qquad c_n = a_n + b_n.
$$
The series $\sum a_n$ is convergent by the alternating test.

We are interested in the convergence of $\sum c_n$. If $\sum c_n$ was convergent, then $\sum b_n = \sum c_n - \sum a_n$ would also be convergent, which is known to be false (divergence of the harmonic series).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried this (see second point), but i was confused, since mathematica says this series is convergent: `SumConvergence[(-1)^n*(2 + (-1)^n)/(n + 1), n]`

Comment: @Gaste: never trust a machine ;) Have you never read/seen science fiction?

Comment: @Siméon. Very good point !

Answer (score 0):

If you sum two successive terms (for indices $2n-1$ and $2n$), you get

$$\frac{3}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{6n-2n-1}{2n(2n+1)}= \frac{4n-1}{2n(2n+1)}$$

And its sum is not convergent, thus your series is not either.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the partial sums:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n \frac{2+(-1)^n}{n+1}=\frac{2}{1}-\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{4}+...+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+...=2\sum_{k \leq N+1 \text{ odd}} \frac{1}{k}$$
and this diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,{2+ \pars{-1}^{n} \over n + 1}
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bracks{{3 \over 2n + 1} - {1 \over 2n + 2}}
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{4n + 5 \over \pars{2n + 1}\pars{2n + 2}}
\end{align}
The 'serie general term' is $\quad\sim 1/n\quad$ when $\quad n \gg 1.\quad$The series $\color{#ff0000}{\large diverges}$ as the harmonic one.